# Django 1.5, images are not displayed, static files

Tags: python, django, image

I'm a fresher in Django 1.5 and I have some problems with images.

I have images in my folder (C:\Users\Neitrosha\PycharmProjects\ecomstore\static\images\products)
There are two folders - 'thumbnails' and 'main' to store images.

my settings.py are:

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'


 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     'C:\Users\Neitrosha\PycharmProjects\ecomstore\static',
 }

 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
     "django.core.context_processors.debug",
     "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
     "django.core.context_processors.media",
     "django.core.context_processors.static",
     "utils.context_processors.ecomstore",
  )
```

I'm using this code on my 'category.html':

```
 {% extends "catalog.html" %}
   {% block content %}
   {% load staticfiles %}
   <h1>{{ c.name }}</h1>
   {{ c.description }}
   <br /><br />

   {% for p in products %}
       <div class="product_thumbnail">
       <a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">
           <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/products/thumbnails/{{p.image}}"  alt="{{ p.name }}" class="bn" />
           <br />
           {{ p.name }}
       </a>
</div>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

For example, my browser can see formed links this way:

```
 <div class="product_image" >
    <img src="/static/images/products/main/super_guitar.jpg" alt="Super guitar" />
</div>
```

But it still doesn't work.

How to make this works?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Maybe because of this string in my model

```
 image = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

? But I just write there the name of the image.

Comment: What do you mean “doesn't work”?

Comment: Wait, how is your question related to uploading files?

Comment: There are no images displayed

Comment: kirelagin, I suppose I made the wrong explanation of my problem. You're right

Comment: When you load the website, where does the src link point to? Does the file exist at that spot?

Comment: <img src="/static/images/products/main/super_guitar.jpg">

Do you mean this?
That's what I see when I want to see the code of the page.
And the foto exists there in this folder.

Comment: If you try to load that photo by pasting the link directly in your browser what do you get? If you get an error, what is it. You need to look in the django logs.

Comment: I have no one error, that's strange. The image is not displayed - that's all.

Comment: I forgot to mention. CSS-file works, so I did no mistake with STATIC, at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong with this code:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     'C:\Users\Neitrosha\PycharmProjects\ecomstore\static',
}
```

First you open with a `(` and close with a non-matching `}`.

Second, `\` need to be escaped in python strings. It should probably be:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     'C:\\Users\\Neitrosha\\PycharmProjects\\ecomstore\\static',
)
```

or

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     r'C:\Users\Neitrosha\PycharmProjects\ecomstore\static',
)
```

Comment: Raw Strings are always better.

Comment: The first one was my tipo there, yes.
The second - I did this way, but there is the same result - the broken image, I can't see them.

I really don't know what I should do.

I checked whether I have 'render_to_response' in my model - it is.

But there's an interesting detail - if I write instead of 
     <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/products/thumbnails/{{p.image}}"

the direct link (the path to the image) - it doesnæt work, too. I can't understand it.

Comment: Also I tried to do using this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/.
But it didn't work, too.

And I can't find the mistake, that pissed me off.